# How to execute ADB inside Android app with Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, adb

It possible to run ADB inside android flutter application without root.

There is an application that did it and it works as expected:
https://github.com/nightmare-space/adb_tool

It is using ADB binary compiled for Android like we can see here:
https://github.com/nightmare-space/adb_tool/tree/main/assets/android

However I can't find how it works, even with the full source.

ADB is installed to a strange location as you can see:
[image]

I tried to replicate this but it doesn't work at all.

```dart
final deposit = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
const program = '/data/data/com.example.my_app/files/usr/bin/adb';
ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/android/adb');
List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
var file = File(program);
file = await file.create(recursive: true);
file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
await Process.run('chmod', ['+x', program]);
var results = await Process.run(program, ['--version']); // Permission error.

setState(() {
  _counter += 1;
  textarea.text = results.stdout;
});
```

Comment: Please don't post terminal output as screenshot (even if your screenshot is one of the rare ones that are at least readable without problems). Just copy and paste the content into your question.

Comment: Apps by default don't have access to adb even if you include the adb executable in your app. The only workaround is using enabling adb over IP using an adb USB connection. Afterwards you may be able to connect to adb from within your app. But the adb IP mode is reset on next device reboot.

Comment: The picture is a feature of the adb_tool Android application, it was to illustrate the application can run adb binary and commands without root access. Yes, this is an Android application (Flutter), not a terminal from desktop OS, it seems it is using [dart_pty](https://github.com/Termare/dart_pty) to create pseudo terminal and fork processes.